# insert a tkinter progress bar in a List Comprehensions of Python

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar, list-comprehension

Normally i use a simple loop to insert a indeterminate progress bar in tkinter.
example

```
self.pbar_ind = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="indeterminate")

new_point_in_list = list()
for point in point_in_list:
  self.pbar_ind.step(1)
  self.update()
  if point > 2:
     new_point_in_list.append(point)
```

Now i am using a List Comprehensions to speed my computation

```
new_point_in_list = [point for point in point_in_list if point > 2]
```

i wish to know if it possible to insert in the List Comprehensions the Tkinter progress bar

Comment: Not easily -- The list-comp probably won't speed things up too much.

Comment: this smells like early optimization to me ... what makes you think your original loop was too slow? how big is this list?

Comment: it's an easy example. The list if over of 80 millions of lines

Comment: If you want to speed up the loop, remove the call to `update`. It is probably slowing your code down by two orders of magnitude or more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about performance, remove the call to `self.update()`. It will slow your loop down by up to *three orders of magnitude*. At the very least you should call it only every 1,000 iterations or so.

In a quick test, I can do 10,000 simple calculations that result in 1% of the values being appended to a loop in about .0016 seconds. When I add a call to `update` in the loop, the time expands to 1.0148 seconds.

You said in a comment you have 80 million rows to iterate over. My same code can process 80 million calculations in **12 seconds**, versus over **2 hours** when I add in a call to update.

Converting your code to using a list comprehension will have a negligible effect compared to removing or reducing the calls to update.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Do you suggest other solutions to show the time computation? Thanks